# Creating Samba shares on Windows

Tags: windows-7, samba, smb

I am not very familiar with how SMB and Samba differ. I am using an app on my iPhone that connects to Samba shares to access and play files (AcePlayer) and it seems to not be able to see my Windows shares so I am assuming that Windows sharing differs from Samba.

So, can I create Samba compatible shares on Windows 7 Pro? Or install a program that does create compatible shares?

Comment: Could you clarify "not able to see"? Does it not show your Windows computer at all, or an empty list of shares, or an error message?

Comment: There is no error message, I add as my ip address and none of my Windows shares are displayed so it is difficult to see where the error lies

Comment: Does AcePlayer allow entering the full path to your files? (For example, `\\1.2.3.4\Music\foo.mp3` or `smb://1.2.3.4/Music/foo.mp3` or something similar.)

Comment: Ahhh... When I changed the permissions on the file for Everyone to read the full path did work. So there is something there. maybe the player doesn't work on the directory listings orit is a permissions issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SMB is the *protocol* for network file access. Samba is a program – an *implementation* of SMB for Unixes, and it was intended from the very beginning to be compatible with Windows as much as possible, so no special changes or programs should be needed.

If AcePlayer does not show your computer at all, make sure "Network browsing" (NetBIOS in particular) is enabled in Windows, and that it is not blocked by any third-party firewalls.

Comment: Thanks for the input. The application talks about connecting to Samba shares and I saw a lot on the web about connecting to Samba shares so assumed it was a different protocol to SMB. So itshould be the same whether I connect to Windows shares or Linux shares if I had them set up?

Comment: Yes - the SMB protocol is the same one used by Windows for its shares.  You may also see it referred to as CIFS.  You can use `smb://path` or `cifs://path` on MacOS if you install and enable sharing with Windows systems.  Please note though that there can be **many** reasons a share doesn't show up for you on a device.